# cdplot() analog in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

I'm looking for a conditional density plot like R's built-in `cdplot` function, but using `ggplot2`.

Here's a vanilla `cdplot` example:

```
with(iris, cdplot(Sepal.Length, Species))
```

[image: cdplot example]

In [the `ggplot2` book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387981413) (page 188), it says the following calls should be equivalent:

```
cdplot(x, y)
qplot(x, fill=y, geom="density", position="fill")
```

However, it looks like that behavior broke in some update to `ggplot2` (it also gives a warning saying `` `position` is deprecated ``):

```
with(iris, qplot(Sepal.Length, fill=Species, geom="density", position="fill"))
```

[image: ggplot example]

I found [a blog entry of someone trying to do the same thing](http://rsnippets.blogspot.com/2012/05/porting-cdplot-to-ggplot2.html), but apparently that's now broken too (same warning, `` `position` is deprecated ``):

```
cdens <- cdplot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, plot = F)
x <- seq(min(iris$Sepal.Length), max(iris$Sepal.Length), length.out = 100)
y <- c(cdens[[1]](x), cdens[[2]](x), rep(1, length(x)))
type <- ordered(rep(levels(iris$Species), each = length(x)),
                levels=rev(levels(iris$Species)))
x <- rep(x, 3)
qplot(x, y, geom="area", fill = type, position="identity",
      xlab="Sepal.Length", ylab="Species") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

What's a way to accomplish this?  What broke in these examples?

(I want a `ggplot` solution because it has better axis labeling and legends, especially when the independent variable is a date.)

**Update:** in a comment below, @bouncyball suggested to use `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species))+ geom_density(position = 'fill')`, but that's doing something different:

```
with(data, cdplot(time, cat))
abline(v=as.POSIXct(c('2017-04-01', '2017-03-01')), col='red')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, fill=cat)) + geom_density(position = 'fill')
```

[image]

The `cdplot` result is what I want, I'm not sure what the `ggplot` example is doing.  The `cdplot` result matches the factor ratios for, e.g., March 2017:

```
> with(subset(data, time>'2017-03-01' & time <'2017-04-01'), table(cat))
cat
   <1s    <3s    <5s   <10s   <20s    <1m    <2m    <5m    <1h   <24h    >1d 
175484  31837  19078  16146  15013  20200   1142   1207    944     17      0
```

Comment: don't use `qplot`: `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species))+
    geom_density(position = 'fill')`. In the `qplot` [help file](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/qplot.html) it says that `stat` and `position` are DEPRECATED (file's caps lock, not mine btw)

Comment: For further information see the __Deprecated Features__ section of the [ggplot2 2.0.0 release blog post](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/)

Comment: It seems like their definition of "deprecated" doesn't really match the common usage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation).  In `ggplot` it sometimes means that, but sometimes seems to mean "removed" or "changed" with no migration period.

Comment: I'm fully on board with not using `qplot()`, btw.  Just pulled that example from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use computed variable `count` for stacked density plots, and reorder species levels according to the cdplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, ..count.., fill = forcats::fct_relevel(Species, 
  levels = c("virginica", "versicolor", "setosa")))) +
  geom_density(position = "fill") +
  labs(fill = "Species")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's more complicated than this, but you can use `position_fill` with `geom_density`. Here's two versions, one with the usual legend for the fills, and one with labels, placed at the maximum `Sepal.Length` for each species. You could set the labels a different way, or skip them--I was just trying to kinda mirror the setup of `cdplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
    geom_density(position = position_fill(), size = 0) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0))
```

[image]

```
lbls <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(max_sl = max(Sepal.Length))

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(position = position_fill(), size = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(x = max_sl, y = 1, label = Species), data = lbls, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, nudge_y = -0.02, nudge_x = -0.05, color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2", guide = F) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0))
```

[image]